# getPicklistValues is not working after Creating a Namespace of my developer ORG

Tags: lightning-web-components

In my contact object i have an custom field called `Gender`, It's a global pick list value.

I'm getting Following error

`{"ok":false,"status":404,"statusText":"NOT_FOUND","body":[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]}"`

It was working earlier, After creating a namespace in my ORG it was not working.

```
import GENDER from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.Gender__c";
import CONTACT_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Contact";

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CONTACT_OBJECT })
contactInfo;

@track genderOptions;
@wire(getPicklistValues, {
recordTypeId: "$contactInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
fieldApiName: GENDER
})
genderFieldInfo({ data, error }) {
if (data) {
console.log("picklist gender -->" + data);
this.genderOptions = data.values;
}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <lightning-combobox label="Gender" name="gender"placeholder="Gender" options={genderOptions}
onchange={handleChange} required></lightning-combobox>
```

I tried to Change the code as below.

`import GENDER from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.np1__Gender__c";`

**Getting this error message.**

`LWC1504: Invalid module id "Contact.np1__Gender__c" for type "schema". Explicit use of namespace "np1" in file "enrolmentForm.js" is prohibited. Use default namespace "c" instead.`

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue Resolved. I was Using my LWC in Visual-force Pages.

Previously I defined a name space as `$Lightning.use("c:EnrollmentVf", function() {`

I Missed to change the name space `np1` in my VF page. After changing It's working.

```
    <apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" /> 
    <script>

    var enrollId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.enrollmentId}";
    $Lightning.use("np1:EnrollmentVf", function() {  //Aura app name
    $Lightning.createComponent("np1:enrolmentForm",
    {recordId  : enrollId},
    "lightning",
    function(cmp) {

    }
    );
    });
    </script>
```